# how can I set webview fill_parent in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I create a fragment sample in Android Studio

and delete the label and add the webview look like:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment">


    <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

And it has the margin on the webview..

So, how can I make the webview fill the dragment?

Comment: Can you make your question a bit clearer? Are you trying to get rid of the margins so the web view fills the whole fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove these lines from RelativeLayout:

android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

Comment: Yeah! Also in your web view, try by removing this: android:layout_margin="0dp"
I don't think you need it